# compiling an embedded spidermonkey javascript engine in C++ application

Tags: javascript, c++, header, command, spidermonkey

I downloaded the SpiderMonkey source code using version 1.8.5 Then I successfully built the include files and static library by executing the following commands:

```
autoconf2.13
./configure 
make
make install
```

Now I tried compiling the following code using the command g++

```
 /* Include the JSAPI header file to get access to SpiderMonkey. */
   #include "jsapi.h"

 /* The class of the global object. */
    static JSClass global_class = {
"global", JSCLASS_GLOBAL_FLAGS,
JS_PropertyStub, JS_PropertyStub, JS_PropertyStub, JS_StrictPropertyStub,
JS_EnumerateStub, JS_ResolveStub, JS_ConvertStub, JS_FinalizeStub,
JSCLASS_NO_OPTIONAL_MEMBERS
};

/* The error reporter callback. */
void reportError(JSContext *cx, const char *message, JSErrorReport *report)
{
fprintf(stderr, "%s:%u:%s\n",
        report->filename ? report->filename : "<no filename=\"filename\">",
        (unsigned int) report->lineno,
        message);
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    /* JSAPI variables. */
       JSRuntime *rt;
       JSContext *cx;
       JSObject  *global;

    /* Create a JS runtime. You always need at least one runtime per process. */
       rt = JS_NewRuntime(8 * 1024 * 1024);
       if (rt == NULL)
        return 1;

    /* 
     * Create a context. You always need a context per thread.
     * Note that this program is not multi-threaded.
     */
       cx = JS_NewContext(rt, 8192);
       if (cx == NULL)
        return 1;
       JS_SetOptions(cx, JSOPTION_VAROBJFIX | JSOPTION_JIT | JSOPTION_METHODJIT);
       JS_SetVersion(cx, JSVERSION_LATEST);
       JS_SetErrorReporter(cx, reportError);

    /*
     * Create the global object in a new compartment.
     * You always need a global object per context.
     */
       global = JS_NewCompartmentAndGlobalObject(cx, &global_class, NULL);
       if (global == NULL)
         return 1;

    /*
     * Populate the global object with the standard JavaScript
     * function and object classes, such as Object, Array, Date.
     */
     if (!JS_InitStandardClasses(cx, global))
    return 1;

    /* Your application code here. This may include JSAPI calls
     * to create your own custom JavaScript objects and to run scripts.
     *
     * The following example code creates a literal JavaScript script,
     * evaluates it, and prints the result to stdout.
     *
     * Errors are conventionally saved in a JSBool variable named ok.
     */
    const char *script = "'Hello ' + 'World!'";
    jsval rval;
    JSString *str;
    JSBool ok;
    const char *filename = "noname";
    uintN lineno = 0;

    ok = JS_EvaluateScript(cx, global, script, strlen(script),
                       filename, lineno, &rval);
    if (rval == JS_NULL | rval == JS_FALSE)
    return 1;

    str = JS_ValueToString(cx, rval);
    printf("%s\n", JS_EncodeString(cx, str));

    /* End of your application code */

    /* Clean things up and shut down SpiderMonkey. */
       JS_DestroyContext(cx);
       JS_DestroyRuntime(rt);
       JS_ShutDown();
       return 0;
}
```

The command that I used

```
     " g++ -Ihome/SpiderMonkey/js-1.8.5/js/src/dist/include 
     -Lhome/SpiderMonkey/js1.8.5/js/src/dist/bin -lmozjs185  helloworld.cpp -o             helloworld "
```

the error is :

```
In function `main':
helloworld.cpp:(.text+0x6e): undefined reference to `JS_Init'
helloworld.cpp:(.text+0x94): undefined reference to `JS_NewContext'
helloworld.cpp:(.text+0xba): undefined reference to `JS_SetOptions'
helloworld.cpp:(.text+0xcb): undefined reference to `JS_SetVersion'
helloworld.cpp:(.text+0xdc): undefined reference to `JS_SetErrorReporter'
helloworld.cpp:(.text+0xf2): undefined reference to `JS_NewCompartmentAndGlobalObject'
helloworld.cpp:(.text+0x11a): undefined reference to `JS_InitStandardClasses'
helloworld.cpp:(.text+0x191): undefined reference to `JS_EvaluateScript'
helloworld.cpp:(.text+0x1c8): undefined reference to `JS_ValueToString'
helloworld.cpp:(.text+0x1df): undefined reference to `JS_EncodeString'
helloworld.cpp:(.text+0x1f3): undefined reference to `JS_DestroyContext'
helloworld.cpp:(.text+0x1ff): undefined reference to `JS_Finish'
helloworld.cpp:(.text+0x204): undefined reference to `JS_ShutDown'
/tmp/ccUU9may.o:(.data+0x10): undefined reference to `JS_PropertyStub'
/tmp/ccUU9may.o:(.data+0x18): undefined reference to `JS_PropertyStub'
/tmp/ccUU9may.o:(.data+0x20): undefined reference to `JS_PropertyStub'
/tmp/ccUU9may.o:(.data+0x28): undefined reference to `JS_StrictPropertyStub'
/tmp/ccUU9may.o:(.data+0x30): undefined reference to `JS_EnumerateStub'
/tmp/ccUU9may.o:(.data+0x38): undefined reference to `JS_ResolveStub'
/tmp/ccUU9may.o:(.data+0x40): undefined reference to `JS_ConvertStub'
/tmp/ccUU9may.o:(.data+0x48): undefined reference to `JS_FinalizeStub'
 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, so I want to post the answer for any one else faces the same problem. 
at the compilation of the hellowrold.cpp, you must write helloworld before the used libraries in the command like this

```
g++ hellowrold.cpp -o helloworld -I/your_path_of_include_folder/include/ -L/your_path_of_shared_libraries/lib -lmozjs185
```